# Избежание Text file busy при обновлении программы

Tags: c++, linux

Имеется некое программное обеспечение, которое работает под управлением ОС Linux.
Сам экзешник живет в /usr/bin/, а библиотеки в /usr/lib/.
Раз в час например происходит обновление системы, в результате чего сама программа просто скачивает файлы и пытается распаковать их по директориям. Проблема в том что когда она пытается распаковать экзешник, то система выдает ошибку Text File Busy. Логика то понятна, она пытается переписать саму себя, но вот как этого избежать?
Программа прописана в автостарт используя systemd

Comment: Вместо переписывания сделать перемещение: сперва распаковать файлы в какой-то временный каталог (на той же файловой системе), а уже оттуда перенести в правильное место

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо